# Redirect a range of IPs via OpenVpn

Tags: routes, iptables, openvpn

I can't redirect an ip range through the vpn, it tells me that the VPN server blocks the traffic.

[This is my architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQhrs.jpg)

This is my settings:

- The Subnet is 152.20.20.0 MASK 255.255.255.0
- Client Windows:

  `route add 22.22.22.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.16`
- Server Windows OpenVpn (10.8.0.1):

  It's configured in client to client mode, therefore my Windows client "knows" the gateway under the VPN
- Ubuntu gateway (10.8.0.16):

  `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 22.22.22.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 152.20.20.0/24`

  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

But if I try to trace an IP from the Windows Client (on 22.22.22.0 range) i get:

[Result of tracert from Windows client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W2oD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

I added the following rule to the server:

```
route 22.22.22.0 255.255.255.0
```

And on the server's ccd (ubuntu gateway) file

```
iroute 22.22.22.0 255.255.255.0
```